# How to get all logs by querying on ApexLog

Tags: apex

Hi I want to find all transactions which are taking more than 5 seconds. 
For that I have formed below query and added many users for tracking logs.

```
SELECT LogUserId,Operation,COUNT(Id) FROM ApexLog WHERE DurationMilliseconds > 5000 Group By LogUserId , Operation
```

Whenver I am running this query I am not getting complete analysis since all logs are not getting considered. [Since I am not able to get logs more than 300]

I checked to see if it is considering all logs or not. To Find out I ran below query from RestExplorer

```
/services/data/v34.0/query?q=SELECT+ID+FROM+APEXLOG
```

Here also though logs are increasing, it is giving result as 200 to 300. Which is always changing. I assume that no of logs should be always increasing.
Is there any limit on how many logs salesforce keeps? Is there any documentation on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you refer the Salesforce documentation for [debug logs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_debugging_debug_log.htm), you will find this

> Each organization can retain up to 50 MB of debug logs. Once your
>   organization has reached 50 MB of debug logs, the oldest debug logs
>   start being overwritten.

and then under the [ApexLog object definition](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_apexlog.htm) you will find this

- **Monitoring** — Generated as part of debug log monitoring and visible to
  all administrators. These types of logs are **maintained until the user
  or the system overwrites them**.
- **SystemLog** — Generated as part of system log monitoring and visible
  only to you. These types of logs are **only maintained for 60 minutes
  or until the user clears them**.
- **Preserved** — A system log that is maintained **longer than 60 minutes.
  Used for internal support**.

So every time you query for the logs, you will see different number of records from different transactions that's available at the time of call.

Comment: Thank you @Vamsi Krishna. Is there any way to get SystemLog by making SOQL or REST call?